# How can I stop Facebook "Alice commented on Bob's status" notifications?

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-notifications

I don't want to turn off Facebook notifications entirely because I find them useful for birthdays and event invites. But, I keep getting notifcations about friends commenting on other friends statuses. I'm getting a bit sick of these. How can I make them stop?

Here are my current notification settings:

[image: notification settings]

Answer (score 1):

Go to that individual's ("Alice's") profile page and closer to the right side on the cover photo, (where you'd normally click on "add friend" to request them, but it now says "friends" with a downward arrow because you're already friends with them)... hover your mouse over the word "friends" and a drop down menu will appear.. Then just uncheck the top one that says "Get Notifications"